# Why is form in partial of AngularJS ui.router with class of ng-pristine not rendering?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS and their basic form is not rendering in a partial I have. All other partials are rendering with $stateProvider. I put a h1 header to see if it renders and it does, but the form doesn't render and is visible in the console with a class of ng-pristine. Here is the basic form:

```
 <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input disabled value="I am not editable" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="disabled">Disabled</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I added `ng-submit` to the form. It still wasn't working even after I checked the materialize scripts. Could the Materialze not be working with the partials? My css links in the head of the index.html are above my JS scripts. I have jQuery as my first JS script in the head above the Angular script.

Answer (score 0):

The html you have pasted seems to be working fine in this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mukaqiz/edit?html,js,console,output) I have created. I think there is some issue either with your angular code or with your materialize css version. Can you recheck and mention you angularjs code as well, if its still not working